# Add a column to a dataframe based on another dataframe column and row number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframe now, and I would like to add one column in dataframe section.1.pos named industry, based on the column industry.fama.french.49 in dataframe raw.data., and it is under condition that the column doc_id is the row number of the raw.data, which means that all rows in section.1.pos with doc_id = 1 should have value in new column industry as 2Food.

And the code I tried is :

section.1.pos$industry <- raw.data$industry.fama.french.49[as.numeric(row.names(raw.data))==section.1.pos$doc_id]

How should I change it?

[dataframe section.1.pos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aja2b.png)

[dataframe raw.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HcLi.png)

Comment: Please don't add images of data or code, just add the data itself: it breaks screen-readers, is not searchable, may not fit well on all mobile screens, and is not something we can copy and paste to try in our own console. Just use `dput(head(x))` or a literal `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: What happened with your code? We can't try it because you did not provide a reproducible version of it. Look at the manual page for the `match` function.